# Spring controller endpoint method executed twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, controller

I have the following controller method:

```
@Transactional
@PostMapping(path = "/add")
@Secured({Constants.ADMIN, Constants.DATAMANAGER})
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> addNewCitizens(
        @RequestBody List<Citizen> citizens) {

    // Time out in 30 minutes
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> output = new DeferredResult<>((long) (1000 * 60 * 30));

    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {

        // Long operation...
        output.setResult(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK));

    }

    return output;
}
```

The method usually receives a lot of data and uses it to update my database. For the data I'm testing with right now it takes 3-4 minutes.

For some reason, when it takes a while for it to process the request, it starts all over when it has finished running once, as if it received another request. The Angular front end application from which i sent the request never receives a response in this case. For fast requests it works perfectly. Also, I checked the network tab in Chrome and I can only see one request getting sent to the endpoint in there.

What could be causing this, and what can I do to fix it? Thanks!

Additional info: It only happens when I deploy the service to a remote server - not when I test on my local machine...

Comment: Is it possible that the transaction is timed-out for the long requests and then another attempt is happening as some kind of a fall-back mechanism? I'd recommend you to try playing with `@Transactional` and `@Secured` annotations (removing and adding them back one-by-one) in order to debug this issue.

Comment: I would also add access logging to your servlet container.  For tomcat, look into its access log valve:  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve. This will help you verify that you are only receiving one request from an outside source.

Comment: @DmytroTitov I tried removing both. but the problem is still there. :(

Comment: @hooknc Is there an alternative to this? For some reason, there's no problem when i test it on my own machine. It only happens when I deploy the service to a remote server. I don't have access to any files there, so I wouldn't be able to access the logs created by that. I tried instead: 
`logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=DEBUG
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG`
But it prints out a lot of stuff, and I don't know what to look for.

Comment: You have got yourself a difficult problem.  Is the deployed version of your app fronted by an apache or nginx machine?  Perhaps there is a timeout enabled on that machine that doesn't send any response after an x amount of time.  I still recommend the access log valve and insist that you get access to the logs on that machine.  We log EVERY request to our servers and it has been so valuable and informative.  Also, when you say it takes a long time to handle the request, is that upload time or database transaction time?